# Jquery infinite scroll on Drupal pagination, getting the same results

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, infinite-scroll

I implemented infinite scroll jquery plugin manually on my drupal website. I'm having an issue with a view that contains an exposed filter. Infinite scroll just keeps appending the same data.

For e.g: If at the time of page load our next page is "page=2" and last page is 5, in this case it simply appends the results of "page=2" to current results.

The "nextSelector"(.pager-next) points only to the next page in drupal. So the script loads the next page (e.g:page 2) over and over.

```
$container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : \'div.item-list ul.pager\',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : \'div.item-list li.pager-next > a\',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : \'.item\',   // selector for all items you\'ll retrieve
      bufferPx: 300,
      pixelsFromNavToBottom: \'ul.pager\',
      loading: {
          msgText: \''.t('Loading More...').'\',
          finishedMsg: \''.t('No more posts.').'\',
        },
        state: {
      isDuringAjax: false,
      isInvalidPage: false,
      isDestroyed: false,
      isDone: false, // For when it goes all the way through the archive.
      isPaused: false,
      currPage: 0
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Drupal doesn't numbers pages as wordpress (infinite-scroll initial use) and its paging system  return results if the request page doesn't exist (closest guess).

Add this settings :

```js
$container.infinitescroll({
    (...)
      maxPage : 10 // your pager max pages or see below
      state: {
        currPage: 0 
      },    

    (...)
```

If you can't set the max pages into the javascript you could "hack" Drupal so it doesn't return any results if the page is out of bounds :

```php
    $perPage = 10;
    $total = count($results);
    $qs_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
    $page = pager_default_initialize($total, $perPage, 0);
    if ($qs_page > $page) {
        //out of bounds !!!
        $perPage=0;
    }

    $offset = $perPage * $page;
    $results = array_slice($results, $offset, $perPage,TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to the infinite scroll plugin. It was a problem with the url generated by Drupal.